# Mount VMware images (.vmwarevm) in Snow Leopard with MacFuse

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

Snow Leopard removed the extended file context menus, which for VMware gave the option to mount .vmwarevm files with MacFuse.

Is there a way to mount the .vmwarevm files in Snow Leopard? I'm using MacFuse 2.1.5 Beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround is to drag and drop your `.vmwarevm` file onto the VMDKMounter application. Another is to right click on your `.vmwarevm` file and choose Open With... and find the VMDKMounter application.

You can find `VMDKMounter.app` in `/Library/Application Suport/VMWare Fusion/`.

One last alternative is to use `open` from the command line.

```
open -a /Library/Application\ Support/VMWare\ Fusion/VMDKMounter.app /PATH/TO/Machine.vmwarevm
```

You could try making a service to do this as well but I suspect that VMWare in their next update will include an updated contextual menu item.

---

**Note: Above applies to Fusion v3.**  VMDKMounter was removed from v4 and v5.  See http://communities.vmware.com/message/1827723#1827723

Comment: Thanks! I had seen comments about VMDKMounter on the Web, but since spotlight could not find it on my HD I had assumed it was not installed on Snow Leopard (the 2.0.5 notes say the installer will not install MacFuse on Snow Leopard due to installer instability)

Comment: Unfortunately Spotlight by default won't search for files within system directories (eg. `/Library`). Very frustrating that it's stuck as a user file centric file search.

Comment: You can use mdfind in a terminal as a replacement to spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

More recent versions of Snow Leopard and/or VMware Fusion allow to mount a Virtual Machine by right-clicking on the VM file and choosing the VMDKMounter application.

However, VMDKMounter uses [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) which, unfortunately, is no longer maintained.
More details can be found in [this article of the VMware Knowledge Base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010989).

Please consider also that, even if you have MacFuse installed, you can mount the VM under Snow Leopard only with the 32-bit kernel. To use this kernel you need to reboot the your Mac while holding the 3 and 2 keys.