# How to Mount VMWare (Fusion) Disk Image in Host Machine (Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mount VMware images (.vmwarevm) in Snow Leopard with MacFuse](https://superuser.com/questions/34244/mount-vmware-images-vmwarevm-in-snow-leopard-with-macfuse)

Is it possible to mount the vmware fusion disk image of a Windows 7 x64 VM in a the host Mac OS X?

If so, is it possible to mount this disk while the VM is running?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/34244/mount-vmware-images-vmwarevm-in-snow-leopard-with-macfuse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VMware Fusion comes with an app to do this; it's named VMDKMounter, and is located in **/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/**.  Nathan L is correct that it requires the installation of MacFUSE (which should have automatically been installed when you installed VMware Fusion).

To use it, you should be able to right-click your virtual machine file, choose "Open With", and see VMDKMounter as an option.  If you don't, you can navigate a Finder window to /Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/ and then drag your virtual machine file onto VMDKMounter.  (There are also rumors that just running VMDKMounter once will then populate the "Open With" submenu so that it appears there in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can mount the Windows 7 Vm in vmware Fusion on Osx - this is what desktop virtualization was designed for.

NO you can't "mount it" or start it while it's already running.

You could "suspend" the machine then copy the VM fils to the host Mac ( from wherever it is located) then start it again.  - this would start running the machine at the exact point you suspended the VM

What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: suspending it is not enough, you have to shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install MacFUSE, which is included on the disk. Once you do that, you should be able to mount the disk, but only when VMware is not running.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, VMWare doesn't provide any tools for mounting disk images on MacOS. There is a tool that does this for Windows and for Linux. Even under the latter two, you can't mount the disk image while its instance is running, or even if it's suspended. The instance has to have been shut down first.